# Integrate custom payment gateway in Kentico 9

Tags: kentico

I need to integrate SecurePay with Kentico.I found this article related to custom gateways :

https://docs.kentico.com/k8/e-commerce-features/customizing-and-developing-your-store/e-commerce-customization-examples/creating-a-custom-payment-gateway

Is there any other approach to integrate gateways instead of using default supported by kentico ?

Comment: What did you already try? Where is your code?

Comment: I just want to know if there is any other approach then one provided by Kentico document.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you are asking.  The approach in the documentation is correct and you will have to write some custom code.  If you are looking for a codeless solution, no there is not.

Answer (score 0):

The Kentico documentation is well explained. This is the best method.
Otherwise you can download this plugin from the MarketPlace http://devnet.kentico.com/marketplace/e-commerce/securepay-payment-gateway-provider
and adapt it to your situation. I don't test it, but for you it could be a starting point.